# How can I create an extended PostgreSQL image that automatically creates a directory upon container creation?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

This is what I tried

**.Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:14

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abcd1234

COPY postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf

# A bash script that executes upon a container creation 
COPY postgres_entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]
```

**postgres_entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p vorvault/nfsshare ;
#other code lines not mentioned
```

**I create the docker image named "dashboard_postgres_image" based on the mentioned docker file**

```
docker build --tag dashboard_postgres_image --file .Dockerfile .
```

**No problems until here, but once I create a container of the image i get an error**

```
docker run dashboard_postgres_image
```

The error that I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres_entrypoint.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘vorvault’: Permission denied
```

Comment: By using CMD and RUN commands you tell your image how to bake containers. You can solve permission denied with USER proper setup.

Answer (score 1):

When the container starts, your current working directory is `/`, which means you're trying to create the directory `/vorvault/nfsshare`.

Your script is being executed by the `postgres` user, and the permissions on the root directory (`/`) only allow the `root` user to create files and directories.

Since you're building a custom image, the easiest solution is to create the directory in your `Dockerfile`, where your `RUN` commands are being executed as the `root` user:

```
FROM postgres:14

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abcd1234

RUN mkdir -p /vorvault/nfsshare
```

If you really need this to happen at run time instead of build time, you'll need to override the `ENTRYPOINT` script from the `postgres` image with one of your own.

Comment: I want to have this on the run time only; I will check how to override the entrypoint script